# Despite setting the deployment target to 7.0, on iTunesConnect it says minimum iOS version is 6.0. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'd like to support devices running iOS 7 and above. So I set the deployment target to 7.0 in XCode 7.0.1 (note that this is different from the XCode of two years ago).

[image: Deployment Target is 7.0]

I also kept the base sdk on latest (which is the default).

[image: Default settings]

And yet, here are the Build Details > Device Requirements as seen in iTunesConnect. The minimum version is 6.0. Why? How can I fix this? Thank you!

[image: Minimum is still 6.0]

Comment: This is not a duplicate because we are talking of a new version of XCode. Also, the answer in the "duplicate" is not the solution to this issue. I have figured out the answer and would like to post it so I request that this be reverted back.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the solution that worked for me was to check out the info.plist file. There was a key called MinimumOSVersion that was set to 6.0. I changed it to 7.0 and re-submitted. Now it works as expected.